# Python is returning json response in single quotes not double (Elasticsearch API)

Tags: python, json, elasticsearch, response, dump

I am using `Elasticsearch` library in python to query an elasticsearch server like below:

```
query = {
   "query":{
      "match_all":{}
   }
}
es = Elasticsearch('localhost:9200')
res = es.search(index='myindex', body=query)
with open('response.json', 'w') as out:
    out.write(res)
    # json.dump(res, out) also gives the same result
```

the output I save to file has the format

```
{ 
    'key':'value',
    'key2': {
       'key3' : 'value2'
    }
}
```

**Notice the single quotes here**. I know I can do a simple find and replace or use `sed` to change single quotes to double, however,  I want to know why this is happening when with `curl` from terminal it is not the case.

I would prefer to have the output dumped in a proper `json` format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python dictionary object is not necessarily automatically in json format. The above issue can be solved by using `json.dumps()` on the response like below:

```
query = {
   "query":{
      "match_all":{}
   }
}
es = Elasticsearch('localhost:9200')
res = es.search(index='myindex', body=query)
with open('response.json', 'w') as out:
    out.write(json.dumps(res))
```

This will turn `res` into `json` format like below:

```
{ 
    "key":"value",
    "key2": {
       "key3" : "value2"
    }
}
```